# Parse sql file using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parsing, dump

I have a sql dump file in excess of 3gb containing multiple queries. I want to parse the file into queries using php.

On recommendation from a user on the site I used https://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/ to do the parsing.   The problem is only the first query can be retrieved using this method.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

The dump file is the only relic of the data from the server.

Thanks!

Comment: look for quotes and escaping, and search for `;`

Comment: Why do you want to parse it? why not to restore it into sever?

Comment: Some of the queries have errors in them. I wish to discard the faulty ones. and i have a limited internet connection, so want to make a clean sweep this time

Comment: an sql dump with errors??

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I think the delimiter changes in the file. So unable to search for ;

Comment: the delimiter changes?? Ok, this is starting to sound ridiculous, I'm out...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

is it possible to Split the dump file using "explode( ";", $dumpfile) and afterwards doing a loop calling the function for parsing? You also could use the other delimiter for the explode. Is it possible that there's an unbalanced quotation?

regards

parascus

Comment: yep, looks the best option.

Comment: when a query like: insert into table (fieldA,fieldB) values ('aa;aa','bb'); exists it will broke the correct parsing of the file

Comment: for this you can parse the chunk and if there is an unbalanced quote just add the next chunk to the previous part.

Comment: How do i remove comments or lines staritng with --

Comment: INSERT INTO table (comment) VALUES ("Hi Tom I'm about to use a semicolon improperly; anyway, how are you doing?");

Answer (score 2):

i really found what you want:

[SQL Parser: Parse SQL files and extract query statements](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7192-PHP-Parse-SQL-files-and-extract-query-statements.html) (( via phpclasses.org ))

sample sql file

```
#this is a comment :)

select * from table1 where a=1;

--select commented 2 
select * from
    table2
    where a=2;

#inserting values
insert ignore into `versions`(`release`,`revision`,`name`,`lastupdate`) values ( '1','0','sqlparser',now()); 

#creating tables
create table `tests` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(80) not null default '',
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;

#customs operations
insert into `tests`(`id`,`name`) values ( '1','test ; value'); 
update `test` set `name`='test value update' where `id`='1';
```

output:

```
array (
  0 => 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE a=1',
  1 => 'SELECT * FROM    table2    where a=2',
  2 => 'INSERT IGNORE INTO `VERSIONS`(`release`,`revision`,`name`,`lastUpdate`) VALUES ( \'1\',\'0\',\'SqlParser\',NOW())',
  3 => 'CREATE TABLE `TESTS` (  `Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `Name` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8',
  4 => 'INSERT INTO `TESTS`(`Id`,`Name`) VALUES ( \'1\',\'test ; valiue\')',
  5 => 'UPDATE `TEST` SET `Name`=\'test value update\' WHERE `Id`=\'1\'',
)
```

something really beautiful about this class is this get in count many things like comments, multiple lines, and queries where his values include ";" character.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improved version of the "Principe Orazio" class (which @AgelessEssence has mentioned).

```
class sql_parser
{
    public static function parse($content) {
        $sql_list = [];
        $query = "";
        $lines = explode("\n", $content);
        foreach ($lines as $sql_line){
            $sql_line = trim($sql_line);
            if(($sql_line === "") || (strpos($sql_line, "--") === 0) || (strpos($sql_line, "#") === 0)){
                continue;
            }

            $query .= $sql_line;
            // Checking whether the line is a valid statement
            if (preg_match("/(.*);$/", $sql_line)) {
                $query = trim($query);
                $query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query) - 1);

                $sql_list[] = sql_parser::remove_query_comments($query);
                //reset the variable
                $query = "";
            }
        }

        return $sql_list;
    }

    public static function remove_query_comments($query)
    {
         $sql_comments = '@
              (([\'"]).*?[^\\\]\2) # $1 : Skip single & double quoted expressions
              |(                   # $3 : Match comments
                  (?:\#|--).*?$    # - Single line comments
                  |                # - Multi line (nested) comments
                   /\*             #   . comment open marker
                      (?: [^/*]    #   . non comment-marker characters
                          |/(?!\*) #   . ! not a comment open
                          |\*(?!/) #   . ! not a comment close
                          |(?R)    #   . recursive case
                      )*           #   . repeat eventually
                  \*\/             #   . comment close marker
              )\s*                 # Trim after comments
              |(?<=;)\s+           # Trim after semi-colon
              @msx';


        $query = trim( preg_replace( $sql_comments, '$1', $query ) );

        // Remove the last ;
        if(strrpos($query, ";") === strlen($query) - 1) {
            $query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query) - 1);
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
$sql_lists = sql_parser::parse(file_get_contents("test.sql"));
print_r($sql_lists);
```

Comment: Does this handle INSERT statements containing text with newlines?

Comment: @acoder Yes, it dose.